# Can I define before usage

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include

I have cpp and h of class file. Class implementation contains `wcsncpy` function that only might be used if defined `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. It works if I place `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before all header inclusions. But why I can't place this line after headers or event just before `wcsncpy` usage?

UPD

According to my understanding I can do `#define` in code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

#define a

#ifdef a
    std::wcout << _T("hello") << std::endl;
#endif

}
```

Why definition below not works?

```
int main(void)
{
 ...
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    wcsncpy(dest, src, 4); 

 ...
}
```

Comment: if `#define` impacted previous lines, then what would `#undef` mean?

Comment: Because if you place it after then it didn't exist when the warning checks for it. You can tell you compiler do define it everywhere without having to put it in code, just need to find the flag/option depending on compiler/IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress a warning (even this one is treated as error by default) locally with [pragma warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx):

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996) // 'wcsncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe.
    wcsncpy(dest, src, 4); 
#pragma warning(pop)
```

It is even possible to wrap this in more readable macros with Microsoft-specific [__pragma keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx):

```
#define DISABLE_CRT_SECURE_WARNINGS() \
    __pragma(warning(push))           \
    __pragma(warning(disable: 4996))

#define RESTORE_CRT_SECURE_WARNINGS() \
    __pragma(warning(pop))

...
DISABLE_CRT_SECURE_WARNINGS();
wcsncpy(dst, src, 4);
RESTORE_CRT_SECURE_WARNINGS();
```

Comment: It would also be a lot simpler if you just used ``wcsncpy_s`` instead. It doesn't make a lot of sense to change the code to use ``#pragma warning`` and not just use the non-deprecated version. You could disable C4996 for your whole project via the command-line ``/wd4996`` or add the define via the command-line ``/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS``. The purpose of the ``_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`` macro is to make it possible to ignore only the C4996 warnings from the CRT, but leave any other C4996 warning visible. If you are just going to ignore all the deprecation warnings, then disable them globally.